# GeoNetwork 4.2.1 (Debian) : install error message

Tags: java, geonetwork, tomcat, apache

I'm a newbie with GeoNetwork. I work on a Linux Debian server. I downloaded the last war file v4.2.1. I pasted it into /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps. The GeoNetwork log is below. What could be wrong?

UPDATE

I checked permissions. I followed the manual for configuring the database. But it still does'nt work. I'm taking the liberty to paste new geonetwork logs :

```
2022-11-16T12:04:32,245 WARN  [geonetwork.databasemigration] -   - Migration: 

 

    > Exception running migration for version: 4.2.1-0 subversion: SNAPSHOT.
           > Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           > 2022-11-16T12:04:32,263 ERROR [jeeves] - JeevesContextLoaderListener:
           > Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
           > [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]:
           > Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean
           > property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
           > [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]:
           > Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean
           > property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
           > ~[spring-beans-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
           >         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
           > ~[spring-beans-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
           >         …
           >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           > 
           > Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
           > Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(
           > Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot
           > create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.fao.geonet.DatabaseMigration.postProcessAfterInitialization(DatabaseMigration.java:122)
           > ~[gn-web-app-4.2.1-0.jar:?] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot
           > create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
           > ~[commons-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0] Caused by:
           > org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Connection reset
           >         at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)
       ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgis.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:155)
       ~[postgis-jdbc-1.3.3.jar:?]
           >         at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:55)
           > ~[commons-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
           > 
           > Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
           >         at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
       ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Relais brisé (pipe) (Write failed)
           >                 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
       ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:355)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >                 at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)
       ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >                 at 
           > 
           > Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
           >         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
       ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
       ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
       ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
           > ~[?:1.8.0_332]
           >         at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
           > ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)
       ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
           >         at org.postgis.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:155)
       ~[postgis-jdbc-1.3.3.jar:?]
           > 
           > 2022-11-16T12:04:32,284 FATAL [jeeves.engine] - Raised exception
           > during init 2022-11-16T12:04:32,284 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -   
           > Exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
           > Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
           > [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]:
           > Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean
           > property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           > 2022-11-16T12:04:32,285 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Message   : Error
           > creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
           > [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]:
           > Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean
           > property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           > 2022-11-16T12:04:32,288 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Stack     :
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
           > [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]:
           > Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean
           > property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset) Caused by:
           > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
           > creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset) Caused by:
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.fao.geonet.DatabaseMigration.postProcessAfterInitialization(DatabaseMigration.java:122)
           > Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
           > Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Connection
           > reset
           >         at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571)
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
           >         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
           >         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
           >         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
           >         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)
           >         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259)
           >         at org.postgis.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:155)
           >          Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
           >         at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
           >         Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Relais brisé (pipe) (Write failed)
           > 
           > Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
           >         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) Caused
       by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
           > Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
           > [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
           > Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
           > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
           > .factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
           >         ... 49 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL
           > error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.fao.geonet.DatabaseMigration.postProcessAfterInitialization(DatabaseMigration.java:122)
           > Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
           > PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
           >         at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
           > Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Connection
           > reset
           >         at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
           > 
           > 
           > Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
           >         at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
           >         Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Relais brisé (pipe) (Write failed)
           >                 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) Caused by:
       java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
           >         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
```

Comment: Please stop changing the question or at least keep the original error and add the new one. Now my answer is not related to the current content of your question :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems GeoNetwork is trying to create the default database in `/var/lib/tomcat` where it doesn't have write permissions.

I'd suggest you to follow the instructions in [the manual](https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/en/install-guide/configuring-database.html) for configuring the database and change the database type to Postgres (probably it's using the default H2 database) or modify the database name property `jdbc.database` in `/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/jdbc.properties` to point to a place where the user `tomcat` can write (by default it points to `~/gn`, that's Tomcat home).

In addition, if you are running Tomcat installed from the Debian APT repositories and it's using SystemD you probably will need to customise the service unit and add the place where you want to store the database as writable directory.

Comment: Thanks. I uncommented the dialect to use (postgresql/postgis) in /WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml .
Moreover, i tried to update the WEB-INF/config-db/jdbc.properties file with relevant connection information. I succeed in seting username, password, database, host, port. But i fear to have failed in seting the jdbc.connectionProperties line. Wwhat is the expected information for this line ? And how to set it ?

Comment: It depends on the type of database you are using. This property is used in the JDBC URL, appended  after the database to add extra properties to the connection. For example for H2 the default value is `LOCK_TIMEOUT=20000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` generating a URL like `jdbc:h2:${jdbc.database};NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE;${jdbc.connectionProperties:LOCK_TIMEOUT=20000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE}`
For Postgres the default value is empty. The property can be used for altering the search_path or other properties. Check  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-parameters if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Debian are you using? If you are using debian10 or newer, this is probably due to java version issue. geonetwork does not support the java 11 and java 8 is not supported by debian after debian 9.